# @TestPropertySource Class Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, properties-file

I'm creating a `TestClass` using a class Propiedades which has `@PropertySource` annotation.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:${services.properties}test-app/.properties")
public class Propiedades {

    @Value("${db.name}")
    public String dbName;

    @Value("${db.jndi}")
    public String dbJNDI;

    @Value("${db.owner}")
    public String dbOwner;

}
```

As you can see I'm loading the `.properties` file from a external location relative to the server where the app is deployed. `services.properties` is a env variable for the server which has a route to a specific folder.

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Propiedades.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application-test.properties")
public class IncidenciaServicioServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    Propiedades propiedades;
    
    @Test
    public void isPropertySetup() {
        String output = propiedades.dbName;
        
        Assert.assertEquals("testDb", output);
    }
    
}
```

When running the test I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Propiedades]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'services.properties' in value "file:${services.properties}test-app/.properties"
```

Why is it trying to load the properties from that path?, shouldn't it be reading from `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `Spring` does not work like you expect. It always tries to load properties specified in `@PropertySource` first then overrides them with values provided with `@TestPropertySource` annotation.

So one of the ways to workaround your issue is to use `ignoreResourceNotFound` flag for `@PropertySource` annotation:

```java
@PropertySource("file:${services.properties}test-app/.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class Propiedades {
   // ... your properties
}
```

In this case `Spring` will ignore the fact it can not find the properties specified with `@PropertySource` and continue using values from `@TestPropertySource`

Or alternatively, you need to provide value for your `${services.properties}` env variable while tests run so it is resolved to correct path to property file.