# How do I resolve a property placeholder with a @TestPropertySource value?

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have trouble getting a placeholder resolved with a `@TestPropertySource` value in my test

Here's an MRE:

```java
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-app")
public class GatewayMeta {
    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String port;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    private List<Server> servers;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        if (servers == null) {
            servers = List.of("http://localhost:" + port);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServerPropertiesTest.ServerPropertiesTestConfig.class)
class ServerPropertiesTest {
    @Autowired
    ServerProperties serverProperties;
    @Test
    void ifNoServerSpecified_serversHasOneServerMatchingLocalhostServerPort() {
        List<String> servers = serverProperties.getServers();
        assertThat(servers).hasSize(1);
        String server = servers.get(0);
        assertThat(server).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8080");
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)
    @Import(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class)
    @TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=8080")
    static class ServerPropertiesTestConfig {
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'server.port' in value "${server.port}"
```

I also tried specifying a `.properties` file in `locations` (maybe, `properties` only enrich already existing properties?)

```java
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties",
        properties = "server.port=8080")
```

The result is the same regardless of whether `*.properties` contains the key or not. It seems `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't care about my `@TestPropertySource` at all

I also tried this:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)
    @Import(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class)
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties") // has the property set to 8080
    @TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=8000") // will it override?
    static class GatewayMetaTestConfig {
    }
```

No exception, but `@TestPropertySource` is completely ignored and its value doesn't override the one specified in the `.properties` file

Is there some *other* `*PostProcessor` for `@TestPropertySource` (not `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`) that I need to import?

I visited these similar posts, but they don't appear helpful: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76197024/testpropertysource-and-value-not-loading-properties-in-tests), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854424/testpropertysource-class-could-not-resolve-placeholder), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855874/testpropertysource-with-dynamic-properties)

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

For the reason I don't comprehend, `@TestProperySource` should be at your *test class*, not *test configuration*

Also, you don't need a regular `@PropertySource` or even, it surprised me the most, a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

Here's the correct version:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServerPropertiesTest.ServerPropertiesTestConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=8000")
class ServerPropertiesTest {
    @Autowired
    ServerProperties serverProperties;
    @Test
    void ifNoServerSpecified_serversHasOneServerMatchingLocalhostServerPort() {
        List<String> servers = serverProperties.getServers();
        assertThat(servers).hasSize(1);
        String server = servers.get(0);
        assertThat(server).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8080");
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)
    static class ServerPropertiesTestConfig {
    }
}
```